# Matlab doesn't run Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, matlab

I'm trying to run a macro from an Excel workbook in Matlab, however while the workbook opens, the macro doesn't run.

I wrote this code:

```
ExcelApp = actxserver('Excel.Application');
ExcelApp.Visible = 1;
ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\nx\Documents\Test.xlsm"); 
ExcelApp.Run("ThisWorkbook.hello"); %also tried without 'thisworkbook'
ExcelApp.Quit;
ExcelApp.release;
```

The macro I made is for testing the Matlab script so it's very simple, it's just a `MsgBox "Hello"`. But I also tried a more complicated macro which, among other things, creates a folder but no folder was created when I run my Matlab script.

If you know why my Matlab script is not running my macro, thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** I just found that the matlab script put in the `ans` variable `'ActiveX VT_ERROR: '` when running the line `ExcelApp.Run("ThisWorkbook.hello");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem came from this line `ExcelApp.Run("ThisWorkbook.hello");` and I needed to write `ExcelApp.Run('hello');` instead.

So ThisWorkbook didn't work as well as the double quote.